# How can i use gsub to replace "0" (only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, replace, zero, gsub

gsub('$0\n','') isn't working

I would prefer something similar.  I want:
(note the 10 and 20 have to work with 0 not being replaced in them).

```
If I have:
23
12
 0
15
 9
 0
10
20
 0


I want:
23
12

15
 9

10
20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to convert this to an array to re-process it, but the same thing can be done with a regular expression:

```
string.gsub(/^\s+0+$/m, '')
```

The `/m` part is key and it makes the expression operate in multi-line mode, that is `^` and `$` refer to the beginning and ending of a line, not the beginning and ending of the string as is usually the case.

Comment: that didn't work (no error but no effect, it still left the zeroes). This is actually part of a ruby loop. i tried gsub! but that gave blanks for everything.

Comment: gsub(/^\s+0+$/m, '') didn't, but ah, but this did, gsub(/^0$/m, '') maybe ruby differences? I'll update your answer and check it to give you the points.

Comment: Ah, in your input you had spaces padding your zeros so it was part of the regular expression. Perhaps `/^\s*0+$/m` is what you're looking for if they're optional.